# Can't figure out stored procedure, error at END

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I was hoping you could help me out...

I do know some SQL, but I'm new to mySQL... and there's this simple query that I just can't figure out what's wrong with it:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE inserttoscrapbookSD
(owner1 VARCHAR(50),
poster1 VARCHAR(50),
Scrap1 VARCHAR(50),

)
BEGIN

INSERT INTO scrapbook (Owner)

VALUES(owner1)

END
```

I know there are a lot of variables being passed, but just using one variable at the moment because if it works for one, it'll work for all. I tried with and without a semicolon ( ; ) at the end of `END` and `VALUES(owner1)` but no luck. It says:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ') BEGIN INSERT INTO scrapbook (Owner) VALUES(owner1) END' at
>   line 6

Comment: I fixed the formatting of the error; please fix the spelling mistakes (_i_ -> _I_, _u_ -> _you_, etc.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is you need to change the delimiter while you define the stored proc, which allows you to use semicolons `;` within your stored proc code without finishing the create command.

Try this:

```
delimiter //

CREATE PROCEDURE inserttoscrapbookSD (
    owner1 VARCHAR(50),
    poster1 VARCHAR(50),
    Scrap1 VARCHAR(50)
)
BEGIN

INSERT INTO scrapbook (Owner)

VALUES(owner1);

END
//

delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try removing the comma after the last parameter